# iOS app EULA in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, eula

I'm reading the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html) looking for information about the EULA of submitted apps, and in `Editing and Updating App Information > Editing the EULA` they explain how to edit this information, but they don't say if you can edit it anytime you submit an update of the app, or it requires your app to be in certain status... I think it would be possible to update this information as well if you are updating your app binary, without having to rename the app or anything like that, but could somebody confirm that it is that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, even without releasing an update, you can always change the EULA. You find the `Edit` button at the bottom of your application overview page.

[image]